# Error when calculating average scores with NumPy: 'ufunc add' did not contain a loop

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, average, numpy-ufunc

I'm encountering an issue when trying to calculate the average scores of students using NumPy. The code I've written is giving me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> average_scores = np.nanmean(numeric_columns, axis=1)
> ...
> numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np

# Defining anything that could be missing in someone else's data
missing_values = ['N/A', 'NA', 'nan', 'NaN', 'NULL', '', '']

# Defining each of the data types
dtype = [('Student Name', 'U50'), ('Math', 'float'), 
         ('Science', 'float'), ('English', 'float'), 
         ('History', 'float'), ('Art', 'float')]

# Load data into a numpy array
data = np.genfromtxt('grades.csv', delimiter=',', 
                     names=True, dtype=dtype,
                     encoding=None, missing_values=missing_values,
                     filling_values=np.nan, ndmin=2)


# Get all the field names (column names) in the structured array
field_names = data.dtype.names


# Extract the numeric columns by checking their data type
numeric_columns = data[[field for field in field_names if data[field].dtype == float]]


# Calculate the average score for each student
average_scores = np.nanmean(numeric_columns, axis=1)

print(average_scores)
```

**Here is my data in the 'grades.csv' file:**

```
Student Name,Math,Science,English,History,Art
Alice,90,88,94,85,78
Bob, 85,92,,88,90
Charlie,78,80,85,85,79
David,94,,90,92,84
Eve,92,88,92,90,88
Frank,,95,94,86,95
```

**What I've Tried**
I've tried loading the data, filtering the numeric columns, and calculating the average scores using np.nanmean(). I've also made sure to handle missing values appropriately.

**EXPECTATIONS**
I expected the code to calculate and print the average scores for each student without errors.

**REQUEST FOR HELP**
I'd appreciate any assistance in understanding the cause of the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: can you print `numeric_columns`?

Comment: @hpaulj                                                             
data.shape:  (6, 1)
Numeric Columns:
[[(90., 88., 94., 85., 78.)]
 [(85., 92., nan, 88., 90.)]
 [(78., 80., 85., 85., 79.)]
 [(94., nan, 90., 92., 84.)]
 [(92., 88., 92., 90., 88.)]
 [(nan, 95., 94., 86., 95.)]]
numeric_columns.shape:  (6, 1)

Comment: Instead of converting numpy array, pandas dataframe will be the easier workaround to resolve your issue, it also handle missing values appropriately, and you can append the average back to the student. It allows you to then export it back into the csv in a nice format. **Refer to sample below.**

Comment: see the `()`?.  You have a structured array, with a compound dtype (with 5 float fields).  `nanmean` works with a regular array with float dtype.  `data` is a structured array with 6 fields.  You just removed the non-float field.

Comment: What does `np.array(numeric_columns.tolist())` produce?  (6,5) or (6,,1,5) float array?

Answer (score 1):

The function `np.nanmean()` is correct as it [ignores the NaN values, read documentation.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

For your example, your numeric columns is a heterogeneous (multi-type) array. You can resolve this by converting it to a homogeneous (single-type) array with the `array.astype()` function.

Try this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your sample txt:

```
In [2]: txt='''Student Name,Math,Science,English,History,Art
   ...: Alice,90,88,94,85,78
   ...: Bob, 85,92,,88,90
   ...: Charlie,78,80,85,85,79
   ...: David,94,,90,92,84
   ...: Eve,92,88,92,90,88
   ...: Frank,,95,94,86,95'''
```

You'vw handled `genfromtxt` as well as anyone I've seen on SO:

```
In [3]: # Defining anything that could be missing in someone else's data
   ...: missing_values = ['N/A', 'NA', 'nan', 'NaN', 'NULL', '', '']
   ...: 
   ...: # Defining each of the data types
   ...: dtype = [('Student Name', 'U50'), ('Math', 'float'), 
   ...:          ('Science', 'float'), ('English', 'float'), 
   ...:          ('History', 'float'), ('Art', 'float')]
   ...: 
   ...: # Load data into a numpy array
   ...: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', 
   ...:                      names=True, dtype=dtype,
   ...:                      encoding=None, missing_values=missing_values,
   ...:                      filling_values=np.nan, ndmin=2)
```

`data` is a structured array; `ipython's` display is the `repr`, so it shows dtype:

```
In [4]: data
Out[4]: 
array([[('Alice', 90., 88., 94., 85., 78.)],
       [('Bob', 85., 92., nan, 88., 90.)],
       [('Charlie', 78., 80., 85., 85., 79.)],
       [('David', 94., nan, 90., 92., 84.)],
       [('Eve', 92., 88., 92., 90., 88.)],
       [('Frank', nan, 95., 94., 86., 95.)]],
      dtype=[('Student_Name', '<U50'), ('Math', '<f8'), ('Science', '<f8'), ('English', '<f8'), ('History', '<f8'), ('Art', '<f8')])

In [5]: field_names = data.dtype.names
   ...: # Extract the numeric columns by checking their data type
   ...: numeric_columns = data[[field for field in field_names if data[field].dtype == float]]

In [6]: numeric_columns
Out[6]: 
array([[(90., 88., 94., 85., 78.)],
       [(85., 92., nan, 88., 90.)],
       [(78., 80., 85., 85., 79.)],
       [(94., nan, 90., 92., 84.)],
       [(92., 88., 92., 90., 88.)],
       [(nan, 95., 94., 86., 95.)]],
      dtype={'names': ['Math', 'Science', 'English', 'History', 'Art'], 'formats': ['<f8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8'], 'offsets': [200, 208, 216, 224, 232], 'itemsize': 240})
```

This is (6,1) shape with 5 fields.  The size 1 dimension is there because you specified `ndmin=2`.  Without that it would be (6,).

`nanmean` can't work with this compound dtype.  There are several ways of converting to a simple float array.  `astype/view` work, so does:

```
In [7]: x=np.array(numeric_columns.tolist())
In [8]: x.shape
Out[8]: (6, 1, 5)
In [10]: np.nanmean(x[:,0,:], axis=1)
Out[10]: array([87.  , 88.75, 81.4 , 90.  , 90.  , 92.5 ])
```

Another converter:

```
In [12]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [13]: y=rf.structured_to_unstructured(numeric_columns[:,0])
In [14]: y
Out[14]: 
array([[90., 88., 94., 85., 78.],
       [85., 92., nan, 88., 90.],
       [78., 80., 85., 85., 79.],
       [94., nan, 90., 92., 84.],
       [92., 88., 92., 90., 88.],
       [nan, 95., 94., 86., 95.]])
```

Comment: that worked for printing out the average_scores 
but now how would I do this 
data = np.column_stack((data, average_scores))
because its saying that no common Dtype exists for the given inputs. For example they could not be stored in a single array unless the type is object

Comment: Adding the averages to the `data` structure is a new task.  `data` is a (6,1) array with a 6 field compound dtype (or (6,) without without the `ndmin=2`).  `average_scores` is a (6,) (or (6,1)) float dtype array.  `dstack`, one of `concatenate` family of functions, joins  like `dtype` arrays on a (new) 3rd axis.  I suspect what you really want is a new structured array with the 6 fields of `data` plus a new field with the averages.  Nothing in  the 'stack' family will do that.  There may be a function in `recfunctions` that could.  I could also do it from scratch.